# Does Matlab's fminimax apply Pareto optimality?

Tags: python, matlab, optimization

I am working on multi-objective optimization in Matlab, and am using the `fiminimax` in the Optimization toolbox. I want to know if `fminimax` applies Pareto optimization, and if not, why? Also, can you suggest a multi-objective optimization package in Matlab or Python that *does* use Pareto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [`fminimax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminimax.html) and [`fgoalattain`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fgoalattain.html) it looks like the [answer is no](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/316242). However, the genetic algorithm solver, [`gamultiobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/gamultiobj.html), is Pareto set-based, though I'm not sure if it's the kind of [multi-objective optimization function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization#A_posteriori_methods) you want to use. `gamultiobj` implements the [NGSA-II](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109%2F4235.996017) evolutionary algorithm. There's also [this package](http://pcdomino.rts.tu-harburg.de/Inter/lectureE14.nsf/720dc6235ba3559b41256a1d002a1be2/7b3ab9df2e63ca27c125739f0054fcd3?OpenDocument) that implements the Strengthen Pareto Evolutionary Algorithm 2 (SPEA-II) in C with a Matlab `mex` interface. It's a bit old so you might want to recompile it (you'll need to anyways if you're not on Windows 32-bit).

Comment: Do you know any package for python?

Answer (score 1):

For python, [DEAP](https://code.google.com/p/deap/) may be the one you're looking for. Extensive [documentation](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/default/index.html) with a lot of real life examples, and a really helpful Google Groups forum. It implements two robust MO algorithms: NSGA-II and SPEA-II.

**Edit (as requested)**

I am using DEAP for my MSc thesis, so I will let you know how we are using Pareto optimality. Setting DEAP up is pretty straight-forward, as you will see in the examples. Use [this one](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/dev/examples/ga_onemax.html) as a starting point. This is the [short version](https://code.google.com/p/deap/source/browse/examples/ga/onemax_short.py?name=dev), which uses the built-in algorithms and operators. Read both and then follow these guidelines.

As the OneMax example is single-objective, it doesn't use MO algorithms. However, it's easy to implement them:

- Change your evaluation function so it returns a n-tuple with the desired scores. If you want to minimize standard deviation too, something like `return sum(individual), numpy.std(individual)` would work.
- Also, modify the `weights` parameter of the [`base.Fitness`](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/dev/api/base.html#fitness) object so it matches that returned n-tuple. A positive float means maximization, while a negative one means minimization. You can use any real number, but I would stick with `1.0` and `-1.0` for the sake of simplicity.
- Change your genetic operators to [`cxSimulatedBinaryBounded()`](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/dev/api/tools.html#deap.tools.cxSimulatedBinaryBounded), [`mutPolynomialBounded()`](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/dev/api/tools.html#deap.tools.mutPolynomialBounded) and [`selNSGA2()`](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/dev/api/tools.html#deap.tools.selNSGA2), for crossover, mutation and selection operations, respectively. These are the suggested methods, as they were developed by the NSGA-II authors.
- If you want to use one of the embedded ready-to-go algorithms in DEAP, choose [`MuPlusLambda()`](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/dev/api/algo.html#deap.algorithms.eaMuPlusLambda).
- When calling the algorithm, remember to change the `halloffame` parameter from [`HallOfFame()`](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/dev/api/tools.html#hall-of-fame) to [`ParetoFront()`](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/dev/api/tools.html#deap.tools.ParetoFront). This will return all non-dominated individuals, instead of the best lexicographically sorted "best individuals in all generations". Then you can resolve your Pareto Front as desired: weighted  sum, custom lexicographic sorting, etc.

I hope that helps. Take into account that there's also a full, somehow more advanced, NSGA2 example available [here](https://code.google.com/p/deap/source/browse/examples/ga/nsga2.py?name=dev).

Comment: Nice. You might spice up your answer with a few links that specifically answer the original poster's question about using Pareto (those well-known methods do of course – NSGA-II is the same used by Matlab's `gamultiobj`).

Comment: I tried to, but didn't have enough karma. I got a few points thanks to  you now, so I'll 'spice it up' ;)